# What are the differences sending data to a Spring controller inside a JSON objecct using GET or POST request?

Tags: jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and AJAX and I have the following doubt.

If in a view I perform an AJAX request using a JQuery script, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "testResource",
  type: "get", //send it through get method
  data:{
     ajaxid:4,
     userID: "Pippo", 
     emailAddress: "pippo@gmail.com"
  },
  success: function(response) {
    //Do Something
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
  }
});
```

I know that it is sending this JSON object:

```
{
    ajaxid:4,
    userID: "Pippo", 
    emailAddress: "pippo@gmail.com"
}
```

to the controller that handle Http GET Request toward the **`testResource`** resource.

Ok, so in my controller layer I have to create a controller that handle this request.

My doubt is: what change when I send a JSON object using GET or POST?

I think that if I use POST I have to retrieve it from the **Request Body** using the **`@RequestBody`** annotation. And when I use the GET (as in the previous case)?

And also: how can I send these data as request paramter of a GET request?

What is the best solution to send some values to the controller? Send these values as request parameter or insie a JSON object?

Comment: This seems like more of a general HTTP question. I guess you will soon get some nice answers but you'd only do yourself good by reading a bit about differences between HTTP methods in general. Wikipedia should be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send GET request, you should not send a request body. Everything should be requested via URL parameters.

And if you want to handle GET request, read requested url parameters with @RequestParam by annotating method parameter directly.

You can do it like this (example from : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        ...
    }
```